# Servers monitoring for production

Tags: monitoring

I have multiple server on my production server (2 web server, 2 application and 2 database server). I would like to setup a free monitoring tool using which i can monitor all my servers from one server. I want to monitor cpu utilization, database server usage (postgres db).

Please suggest some good free monitoring tool for this purpose. All my servers are red hat 5.7 linux servers.

Comment: Shopping Questions are not allowed on ServerFault.  Details are provided in the FAQ.

Comment: @gWaldo: This is not a shopping question, I wanted to setup a monitoring server for which I have already got answers below.

Comment: nagios,ganglia,monit... these are my favourites...

Comment: @ankit I understand that you are new to the community, but it is what we consider a shopping question, Even though you have set the price at "0".  The community is free to answer your questions (as they have), but this kind of question is frowned upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/). It is fairly easy to setup and gives you trend graphs of your system and applications.

One of your servers need to act as a `munin-master` which gathers, stores and graphs your data. All machines will act as `munin-nodes` (including the one running as master) and will collect data and ship it to the master.

#### Install munin-master

`yum install munin.noarch`

#### Install munin-node

`yum install munin-node.noarch`

When this is done, you need to configure the nodes and master. You should be able to do this by looking at the example configuration files provided with the packages.

Answer (score 3):

[Nagios](http://nagios.org/) is an excellent choice for monitoring. If setting it up by modifying text files is not your cup of tea, you can configure it with [NConf](http://www.nconf.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=main).

Comment: Nagios may be a little bit of over kill for managing 6 servers!

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I started with it when I only had 10 servers to look after. :-)